# How to change a DB2 JDBC connection property after its creation?

Tags: java, jdbc, properties

I'm setting the ClientAccountingInformation property of a DB2 connection before its creation for logging purposes.

```
    this.properties.put("ClientAccountingInformation", "test");
    lDbConection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.connectionString, this.properties);
```

But I need to set a different value everytime this connection is used, because it comes from a connection pool and it is reused by different transactions.

In fact, what I need is:

- Create a connection
- Set the property with value A
- Use the connection
- Give it back to the connection pool
- Get it again for another transaction
- Set the property with value B
- Use the connection
- Give it back to the connection pool

And so on...

Comment: You can't. You have to set the specific property when configuring your connection in the data source or set the property manually per transaction.

Comment: Set the property manually per transaction is what I need. But this only works on the first time (before creating the connection). After that, it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible:

```
    properties.put("ClientAccountingInformation", "test 2");
    lDbConnection.setClientInfo(properties);
```